# Best way to bypass table with over 3000 partition in Hive

Tags: sql, optimization, hive

I have huge table with 8500+ partitions and it uses with join to small table.
I have problem with Hive limit = 3k partitions and execution time.

I use it like this:

```
select 
/* broadcast(a) */
/* streamtable(b) */
/* broadcast(c) */
/* broadcast(d) */
a.fields, b.field, c.field, d.field
from <small_table_1> a
left join (select * from <huge_table> where date_part > 20150100
           union all
           select * from <huge_table> where date_part between 20070100 and 20150100
           union all
           select * from <huge_table> where date_part < 20070100
) b on a.field = b.field
left join <small_table_2> on .....
left join <small_table_2> on .....
```

Is there a better way to optimize my query?

Comment: I should say process three times for all above conditions instead of all at once.

Comment: this question is more about optimizing sql nothing specific to hive